# Backbone View El confusion

Tags: backbone.js

I seem to have run into a problem,

Can anyone spot why nothing is put into the div id "app"??

http://jsfiddle.net/suN5n/1/

From the link:

JS -

```
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var data = {
    first: 'hello',
    second: 'there'
};
var myModel = new MyModel(data);

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: myModel,
    el: $('#app'),
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();     
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.model.toJSON());                        
    }        
});

var myView = new MyView();
```

​
I'm sure it's just me being a BackboneJS noob.

Comment: does $('#app') exist when your backbone code is running?

Comment: Pretty sure it does, check the link to be sure for yourself, I set JSFiddle to domReady the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh, you're trying to pass an object to `.html` when it only takes a string. Use `JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON())` if you want to do something weird like that.

Comment: HAHA, I just realised the exact same thing *facepalm* how embarrassing!